# HQL between two time interval

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

How is the correct format to  use a HQL between 2 intervals of date times.
 I have this SQL in **oracle:**

```
select * from vw_diariorecauda where ts_crea between TO_DATE
('01/10/2013 00:00:00','dd/MM/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
and TO_DATE ('01/10/2013 23:59:59', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

My HQl:

**the field:**

```
private Date tsCrea;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "TS_CREA")
public Date getTsCrea() {
    return this.tsCrea;
}
```

**DAO:**

```
public List<VwDiariorecauda> buscarFecha(Date fecha) {
    log.trace(fecha);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(fecha);
    c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Date fInicio = c.getTime();
    c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

    Date fFin = c.getTime();
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Query query=session.createQuery("FROM VwDiariorecauda WHERE
            tsCrea  BETWEEN :hora1 AND :hora2").setTimestamp("hora1",fInicio).
            setTimestamp("hora2",fFin);
    return query.list();
```

the hql works good but the results is different with the simple sql.
How can I improve this hql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the entity is a view in oracle

Comment: how are the results different?

Comment: some rows are repeated in the list with HQL

Answer (score 0):

Maybe help you if you see the SQL sentences created by your ORM engine. In case you use Hibernate you should use "`<hibernate.showsql>true</hibernate.showsql>`" config parameter. Check if you found any difference between generated sentence and your own sentence.

If sentences are equals, check your params, here should be the matter.